# Pass Vim buffer variable as an argument for external command

Tags: vim, include-path

The problem is that I need to pass include paths to the C++ compiler.
I can define them for each buffer, like:

```
:let b:COMPILER_OPTIONS='-ggdb -I"E:\boost_1_42_0\boost\"'
```

But how do I expand b:COMPILER_OPTIONS on the command line ?

```
:!g++ program.cpp eval('b:COMPILER_OPTIONS')
```

doesn't work.

Or, if this isn't possible, what other ways are there for doing this ?

Comment: Do you want the path to the current file? if so, I believe it's `%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly, but you can define a custom command:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Gpp exe '!g++' b:COMPILER_OPTIONS '<args>'
```

if you want filename completion you can add the `-complete` option:

```
:command! -nargs=1 -complete=file Gpp exe '!g++' b:COMPILER_OPTIONS '<args>'
```

usage:

```
:Gpp program.cpp
```

Comment: directly would just be `:exe '!g++' b:COMPILER_OPTIONS 'program.cpp'`